# Считывание из файла в объект Node JS

Tags: json, node.js

В текстовом файле хранится:

{"login":"art@mail.ru","password":"456adf"}{"login":"art@mail.ru","password":"789"}

Мне надо считать в массив объектов типа:

```
           var userData = {
                login:  params["login"],
                password: params["userpass"]
            };
```

Записываю в файл в формате JSON:

```
            var userData = {
                login:  params["login"],
                password: params["userpass"]
            };

            var str = JSON.stringify(userData);
            fs.appendFile('txt/user.txt', str);
```

А вот как обратно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var fs = require('fs');
   var obj;
   fs.readFile('txt/user.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
   if (err) throw err;
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
   });
```

Comment: Что из себя будет представлять объект obj???

Comment: ваш json объект

Answer (score 3):

Так себе решение, конечно, но покуда не будет вложенных объектов, будет работать. А так, конечно, лучше бы добавить разделитель между записями, например, хотя бы перевод строки (`\n`).

Синхронная версия:

```
var userDataEntries = fs.readFileSync('txt/user.txt')
        .toString()
        .split(/(?={")/)
        .map(x => JSON.parse(x));
```

Асинхронная:

```
fs.readFile('txt/user.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err){
        // Обработка ошибок
        return;
    }

    var userData = data.toString().split(/(?={")/).map(x => JSON.parse(x));
});
```

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда записывать логин и пароль, чтобы их потом можно было считать и проверить? Может удобнее без JSON?

Comment: @bsuart2017, вообще, если новые записи будут добавляться редко, можно просто перезаписывать файл целиком, и тогда уже хранить там обычный JSON-массив. При добавлении, если нет уже загруженного, читать обычным `JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(…).toString())`, затем `.push({ … })`, затем сохранять с `fs.writeFileSync(…)`.